# Working a Macro into larger Sub

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

I am trying to work a single use macro into a Do Until Loop where the macro will loop through the files in my folder. I am having trouble editing the macro to work for this purpose. I know I need to have; Variable for file path, Variable for the prefix to the file, incorporate my count, and the file type ".dat" integrated into the script. Any tips for syntax or streamlining my bulky macro would be greatly appreciated.

```
Sub CSV_Import()
Dim ws As Worksheet, strFile As String

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
'set to current worksheet name

strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("All Files (*.*),*.*", , "Please selec text file...")

With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & strFile, Destination:=ws.Range("A1"))
 .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
 .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
 .Refresh
End With
End Sub
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try wrapping the current code in a loop like this using `Dir`. I was unable to test the `ws.queryTables.Add` bit, but the `Dir` bit does loop appropriately through the files in the specified folder. this also assumes that you want all .dat files in the specified folder.

```
Sub CSV_Import()
Dim ws As Worksheet, strFile As String

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
'set to current worksheet name

strFile = Dir("\path\to\file\*.dat")
Do While Len(strFile) > 0
    With ws.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & strFile, Destination:=ws.Range("A1"))
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
        .Refresh
    End With
    'Debug.Print strFile
    strFile = Dir
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: After a crash this code no longer works, upon refreshing I get the error "Excel cannot find the text file to refresh this external data range." Although the files have not moved and the sheet has not changed either. Any tips?

Comment: I suppose I would try adding `debug.print strfile` after your `Do While` statement. Then have a look at the output to see what it thinks it is looking for. Either that, or try stepping through the code line by line with the F8 key.